# A "concrete" example of a one-sided Hopf algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, examples, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

I came to know from the paper [Left Hopf Algebras](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82735457.pdf) by Green, Nichols and Taft that one may consider a Hopf algebra whose antipode satisfies only the left (resp. right) antipode condition.

To be more precise, let $\Bbbk$ be a field and $(B,\mu,\eta,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ a $\Bbbk$-bialgebra. We say that $B$ is a *left Hopf algebra* if there exists a linear endomorphism $S:B\to B$ such that
$$S(b_1)b_2=\varepsilon(b)1$$
for every $b\in B$ (i.e. $S$ is a left convolution inverse of the identity morphism).

In Section 3 of [Left Hopf Algebras](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82735457.pdf) an "artificial" (in my opinion) example of such an object is provided. In a "recent" paper, [A Left Quantum Group](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305000220), Rodriguez-Romo and Taft provided a new example, which I still consider a bit "artificial". Is anybody aware of some more "concrete" or "natural" examples of this construction?

This question is strictly related to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889576/a-concrete-example-of-a-left-hopf-algebra) on MSE. Maybe that was not the right place where to ask. The only answer it received concerns the quotient $B$ of the free non-commutative k-algebra $k\{X,Y\}$ by the ideal generated by the relation $XY-1$. This is, however, not a one-sided Hopf algebra because the condition $S(x)x=1$ together with $xy=1$ would imply $S(x)=y$ and hence would force $B$ to be a Hopf algebra ($x$ denotes the class of $X$ in the quotient and similarly for $y$).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $B=k\{\dots,x_{-1},x_1,x_2,\dots,  x_n,\dots \}/(x_nx_{n+1}-1: n\in\mathbb Z)$ with $\Delta x_n=x_n\otimes x_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Will not this quotient out all $x_n-x_{n+2}$ too?

Comment: ops, you are right. It's ok because cocommutativity implies $S^2=Id$... I was thinking in Takeuchi's construction, given $C$ a coalgebra, define $C_n=C$ if $n$ odd and $C_n=C^{op}$ if $n$ is even. Then take $T(\oplus_n C_n)$ and $S$ the  extension of the "identity" map going from $C_n\to C_{n+1}$. After that, one should divide by 2 relations: left antipode formula and right antipode formula. Probably the smallest example should be with the smallest non cocommutative coalgebra.

Comment: @MarcoFarinati. Two things: 1) the example you mention in the answer has the same problem of your example on MSE. $S(x_n)x_n=1$ and $x_nx_{n+1}=1$ implies $S(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ and hence the outcome is a Hopf algebra. 2) the example you mention in the comment is exactly the one from the paper "Left Hopf Algebras" referenced in the question: as I already mentioned, it seems to me pretty artificial. I am looking for some genuine and "natural" example, such as quantum groups, physical one-sided symmetries..

Comment: Could I get one of you to explain what is going on in the "Left Hopf Algebras" paper? At the top of page 409, the author introduce a free algebra on noncommutative variables $X_{ij}^r$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $r \geq 0$, modulo relations $(\ast)$ and $(\ast \ast)$, and claim that these relations don't imply $(\ast \ast \ast)$. If we write $Y_r$ for the matrix with entries $X_{ij}$, then $(\ast)$ is $Y_{r+1}^T Y_r = \text{Id}$ for $r \geq 0$, $(\ast \ast)$ is $Y_r Y_{r+1}^T = \text{Id}$ for $r \geq 1$ and $(\ast \ast \ast)$ is $Y_0 Y_1^T = \text{Id}$ (continued).

Comment: But, taking the transpose of $(\ast \ast)$, we have $Y_2 Y_1^T = \text{Id}$, and thus $Y_0 = Y_2 Y_1^T Y_0 = Y_2$ (second equality is $(\ast)$). So $Y_0 Y_1^T = Y_2 Y_1^T = \text{Id}$ (second equality is $(\ast \ast)$), so we have deduced $(\ast \ast \ast)$ from the relations $(\ast)$ and $(\ast \ast)$ after all. I assume I am missing something basic; what?